# Synchronizing Active Directory from Novell LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Is there any tool which copies the structure(all ou's, all cn's) from Novell LDAP to Active Directory?

Answer (score 2):

- export all data from the source directory server into an [LDIF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849) file and then import that the resulting LDIF file into the destination directory

or

- use the [ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/) tool to retrieve the desired entries from the source directory server and deposit those into an LDIF file, then import the resulting LDIF file into the destination server

or

- use the ldapsearch tool to retrieve the desired entries from the source directory server and input the results directly in the [ldapmodify](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/master-the-ldapmodify-command-line-tool/) tool

or

- write a tool using the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/docs/javadoc/index.html?com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/package-summary.html) to retrieve the desired entries from the source and then add them to the destination

or

- use a commercial LDAP synchronization tool

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one time LDIF export and import of the OU structure using Apache Directory Studio would be way easier than Identity Management (IDM).  IDM is not easy to setup.  Also the IDM Active Directory driver out of the box is not designed to sync OUs.  You would have to create a custom IDM LDAP driver.  This is a lot of work and doesn't make sence unless the OU tree you are importing is changing constantly.

Answer (score 1):

There are few key tools that one can use:

1. **Import Conversion Export Utility (ICE) from Novell iManager** - this is a web based tool that will allow you to export entire structure in a ldif format with very little fuss. The following link will give more details on it. http://www.novell.com/documentation/edir873/?page=/documentation/edir873/edir873/data/a5hgmnu.html
2. The other way is to **use the command line ICE tool** as well - you can use if you more comfortable with using BASH. 
   http://www.novell.com/documentation/edir873/edir873/data/a5hgmnu.html#a5hgn0b
3. **Using command line utility like ldapsearch** - i have found it to be very effective so will rate this very highly if you want to automate your LDAP extraction process. Bear in mind that the ldapsearch utility differs on each flavour of UNIX so some of command line options (e.g. ldapsearch -H or -y flag) will not work on Linux (e.g. RHEL) but may work on SUSE / Solaris / Aix. I have experienced this myself so just thought of warning you for the same (i tried moving from Suse to RHEL but got stuck in this trap).
4. **Using command line utility (windows) called ldp.exe** - this is another open source windows command line utility that allows one to write simple powershell script to perform LDAP search - useful if you have windows based workstation (i ran on my own pc). See below link for more details https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771022%28v=ws.11%29.aspx
5. **Use open source LDAP browser** such as **Apache Directory Studio / Gawor's LDAP Browser** which will help export data into CSV / Excel format. The only drawback with this tool is that heavy duty searches sometimes can lead to system being slowed down; for that the other alternative is using Light weight LDAP browser like Jerek Gawor's LDAP utility. http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tools/13765.html will give more details. i have used this tool (Gawor's ldap tool) for large queries as well and its been giving results very quickly.

Having used each of the options over last 5 years, I will recommend using either ldapsearch (for UNIX) or ldp.exe (for windows commnand line) if you are looking to automate this; or Gawor's ldap browser / Apache Directory Studio as potential alternatives if you want to generate standalone extracts.

Answer (score 0):

Novell has a product (now under the NetIQ Product line) called Identity Manager, which can synchronize objects (any object allowed in schema) from eDirectory to many other systems, Active Directory included.  If you have Universal Passwords enabled in eDirectory you can even send the passwords.

This is meant to be used as an Identity Management system, where you can have HR provision users into a central eDirectory instance (as a hub) and then push that data out to all connected systems that meet the criteria you define.

It supports Roles Based Access Control, so that perhaps only people who fall into certain roles get provisioned into certain systems and the like.

Very powerful, and reasonably easy to set up.  There is a free bundle edition included with many of the Novell/NetIQ products if you own them.